# Installing Java 7 on Mac OS X: "A higher version of the JRE is already installed on this system"

Tags: java, macos, java-7, osx-mountain-lion

When trying to install newly released [Java 7 Update 6 for Mac](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1637588.html), the installer terminates printing following error message:

> A higher version of the JRE is already installed on this system

I installed Java 7 Beta before (which actually has been only an internet plugin), which had some problems with updating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleting Java 7 Internet Plugin folder solves the problem (recommended way of uninstalling the beta), the installer is now able to run successfully.

Run

```
sudo rm -rf '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin'
```

or delete `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` on your own.

Do not forget to install [JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html) afterwards, you will not be able to select Java 7 otherwise.

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer, so others with similar questions might benefit of it?

Comment: It beleive there's a / missing before Library in the quoted code.

Comment: You're right, I broke that when editing the answer some time ago. Fixed it.

Comment: There is a more complete answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177665/cant-update-java-due-to-apparently-newer-version-already-installed. In short you may also want to remove the OS X installation of Java so that it doesn't waste space on your hard disk. This is explained in detail in the link provided.